# Get X,Y position of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3x3 list of jQuery divs like so :

```
div1 div2 div3
div4 div5 div6
div7 div8 div9
```

When a div is dragged & dropped I would like to get its X & Y position in relation to the other div elements. so if div1 is dragged to div3 position I need to retrieve the postion 0,3 which represents the new position of div1. Do I need to use a plugin ?

So just to need to override droppable like so and get position :

```
$( ".myClass" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) 
            { 
alert('my position in relation to other divs is '+????
            } 
        });
```

Ive added a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aL3tr/ 
Can the X & Y co-ordinate of dropped item be retrieved ? In this case Y position will always be zero.

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the divs? If you can identify only those nine `<div>` elements, you may be able to do some basic math using the result of the `.index()` jQuery function to calculate the position of a specific element in the grid.

Comment: or you could try `div.offsetTop` and `div.offsetLeft`

Comment: @Anthony Grist please see edit

Comment: Your fiddle is using a sortable.  Are you looking for an answer using a sortable or a droppable?

Comment: @villecoder sortable, but I can update to use a draggable instead if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44R97/ to check the position within the #sortable-list:

```
stop: function() {
    var myPos = $('#sortable').find('li.ui-draggable');
    alert("I am at position "+($('#sortable').find('li').index(myPos)+1));
}
```

Note, that .index() counts from 0. Therefor I added 1 to the result...

Comment: is it possible to get the X position also, in case there are extra columns ?

Comment: for extra columns you would need a table instead of an unsorted list. I'm not sure whether .sortable works with tables, but you could find the y-pos with `$('table').find('tr').index(myElement)` and x-pos with `$('table').find('tr').find('td').index(myElement)`...

Comment: Please note that this function works only for the first dragging-event as expected! If you need the position for more than one dragged element you need to extend the code...

Answer (score 1):

add this to your draggable

```
stop: function(e,ui) {alert(ui.offset.top+","+ui.offset.left);}
```

(update)

ok, for all the siblings

```
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function(e,ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.parent());
            var i=ui.item;
            ui.item.parent().children().each(
                function (i,e) {
                    alert(ui.item.offset().top-$(e).offset().top);
                }
            );
        },
        revert: true
    });
```

here obtaining X relative distance, Y is always 0 but you can obtain it in similar way

Comment: that returns the offset, I'm looking for the X,Y position in relation to the other div elements

Answer (score 0):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aL3tr/10/) to show the coordinates of the clicked element with the following snippet:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    alert("I am at (" + this.offsetLeft + "," + this.offsetTop + ").");
});
```